# Windows.location.assign is not working in a js function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm training on developing a personal web site and I'm at its very beginning.

I need to load a new web page when clicking on a button after some verification on the information entered by the user in the forms' fields.

For that, I made a JavaScript script with an `auth()` function (which is an easy prototype not secure at all, by the way if you know a great tutorial to make a secure web site connection using a database, I'll be grateful if you shared your knowledge with me).

**The problem is**: When I click on the button nothing is happening, why ?

When I tried to put the function in the html file, it's not working too, but when I take the `windows.location.assign(link)` out of the function it's working but it's directly redirecting and it's not what I wanted.

Here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <body>
    <center>
        <form>
            User name : <br>
            <input name="user" type="text" id="user"></br> 
            Password : <br>
            <input name="password" type="password" id="pswd"></br>
            <br>
            <input name="Ok" type="submit" value="Ok" onclick="auth()"><br>
        </form>
    </center>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="id.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my js

```js
function auth(){
    var user = document.getElementById("user");
    var pswd = document.getElementById("pswd");
    var link = 'http://192.168.1.17/index.html';
    if(pswd == "osef"){
        window.location.assign(link);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Tip: if you’re starting to learn web development, learn it properly from the start to avoid getting into bad habits. Old styling tags such as `<center>` is not really supported in HTML5 (use CSS instead) and inline event handlers are bad practice (use the `addEventListener` method instead). Also, the `<br>` is an empty tag so it doesn’t have an empty tag and it should only be used within text paragraphs. It shouldn’t be used to position sections, this should also be done with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues in your code.

1. You are submitting the form when you click on the button
2. you are not getting the values of the input.

For the first issue, use event parameter in click function like `onclick="auth(event)"` and then in the auth function use 
`event.preventDefault()` to prevent the form from submit.

For the second issue you need to get the values of the input like this `document.getElementById("user").value`.

**HTML:**

```
 <center>
        <form>
            User name : <br>
            <input name="user" type="text" id="user"></br>
            Password : <br>
            <input name="password" type="password" id="pswd"></br>
            <br>
            <input name="Ok" type="submit" value="Ok" onclick="auth(event)"><br>
        </form>
    </center>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function auth(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var user = document.getElementById("user").value;
    var pswd = document.getElementById("pswd").value;
    var link = 'http://192.168.1.17/index.html';
    if(pswd == "osef"){
        window.location.assign(link);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Hope this will solve the problem

Comment: Thanks that made the trick !
I understand my mistake with .value missing, but can you explain what is this event parameter event default and why return false ? I

Comment: Event parameter holds the event details, in this case the event is form submit as the button is of type submit . when you click on this button the browser triggers the default event which is submit. To prevent this we can use `preventDefault()` function of the event object to prevent the default action.